# C# Automapper IQueryable - LINQ 2 SQLite - Query returns only parent, nested child always null

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, automapper, iqueryable

Hi people of the internet,

I've been searching on SO for a couple of days now, tried loads of possible solutions but I'm not able to solve my issue in the following test-project. *Please excuse my lack of skill as I'm a self-taught programmer for just over a year now and I'm this is my first question on SO.*

*The situation:*
I've got 2 entity classes `Car` and `Wheel` and want to store and query them from a single db table using c#'s linq to sql(ite).

```cs
    public class Car
    {
        public Int64? Id { get; private set; }
        public string Manufacturer { get; private set; } = "Porsche";
        public double Mileage { get; private set; }
        public Wheel Wheel { get; private set; }

        public Car()
        {
            this.Id = Program.CarCount;
            Mileage = new System.Random(Program.CarCount).Next(0, 500000);

            Program.CarCount++;
        }

        public Car CreateWheels()
        {
           // Adds Wheel 2 Car
        }
    }

    public class Wheel
    {
        public Int64? Id { get; set; }
        public string Manufacturer { get; set; } = "Continental";

        public Wheel() { Id = Program.WheelCount; }
    }
```

Unfortunately as it is a test project for a different project I'm working on I'm not able to split up the raw-data into multiple OR-tables.

To work with a single table instead I flatten them into a single `CarDto` class that matches my single db table.
I flatten both classes into the `CarDto` to be used with LINQ 2 SQLite using AutoMap and assigning the individual db columns.

```cs
    [Table(Name = "Cars")]
    [AutoMap(typeof(Car), ReverseMap = true)]
    public class CarDto
    {
        public CarDto(){ }

        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
        public Int64? Id { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public double Mileage { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public Int64? WheelId { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string WheelManufacturer { get; set; }
    }
```

Mapping between DTO-class and entity-class is done with a mapper `CarMapper` using *AutoMapper* v.9x

```cs
    public class CarMapper
    {
        public IMapper Map => Config.CreateMapper();
        IConfigurationProvider Config;

        public CarMapper()
        {
            Config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddMaps(typeof(CarMapper).Assembly);
            });
            Config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }
    }
```

Interaction with the db is handled via a repository class `CarRepo`containing the mapper and the `DataContext` class of C# Linq2SQL

```cs
    public class CarContext : DataContext
    {
        public Table<CarDto> CarDtos;
        public CarContext(IDbConnection connection) : base(connection) { }
    }

    public class CarRepo
    {
        private string conn;
        CarMapper mp = new CarMapper();
        CarContext CarContext => new CarContext(new SQLiteConnection(conn));
        public IQueryable<Car> Cars { get => Qry(); }

        public CarRepo(string connectionString) { this.conn = connectionString; }

        private IQueryable<Car> Qry()
        {
            return mp.Map.ProjectTo<Car>(CarContext.CarDtos);
        }

        public List<Car> GetAllCarsFromDb()
        {
            var dtosFromDb = new List<CarDto>();
            using (var db = CarContext)
                return mp.Map.Map<List<CarDto>, List<Car>>(db.CarDtos.ToList());
        }

        public void InsertCars(List<Car> cars)
        {
            using (var db = CarContext)
            {
                db.CarDtos.InsertAllOnSubmit(mp.Map.Map<List<Car>, List<CarDto>>(cars));
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

***The problem:***

Insertion and mapping the `CarDto`-table to `Car` works flawlessly.  Running `repo.Cars.Where(car => car.Id <= 5).ToList();` results as expected except for the nested object `Wheel`, which always returns as null. The problem exists when projecting a car-query and probably lies in the mapping of the query expression. Looking at the resulting query this seems obvious.

```sql
SELECT[t0].[Id], [t0].[Manufacturer], [t0].[Mileage]
FROM[Cars] AS[t0]
WHERE[t0].[Id] <= @p0
```

Running the following mapping `mp.Map.Map<List<CarDto>, List<Car>>(db.CarDtos.ToList());` works and delivers `Car` including `Wheel` instances.

I tried loads of solutions (custom mappings,... )  and went through the AutoMapper documentation but wasn't able to fix my problem. Hope someone can help me.

Cheers from germany!
Henrik

***EDIT:***
P.s. I added a gist https://gitlab.com/snippets/1957648
https://gist.github.com/henrikherr/29eb2913d403ab1d6bede52ed011869a

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: Thanks @LucianBargaoanu . The resulting expression mirrors the missing `Wheel` selection. `expression = {Table(CarDto).Select(dtoCarDto => new Car() {Id = dtoCarDto.Id, Manufacturer = dtoCarDto.Manufacturer, Mileage = dtoCarDto.Mileage})}`

Comment: Make the setter public.

Comment: Thanks @LucianBargaoanu! But making the setter public sadly doesn't help. Also the "standard" mapping like `mapper.Map<CarDto,Car>(dto)`  works fine, returning the  `Car` containing the nested `Wheel` (from the dto-db) and vice versa.

Comment: That's not relevant, `Map` is a whole other business. A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu thanks again for your time. I created a gist which should be executable. I skipped mocking the DataContext as I read that it's a lot of work and messy. So the Program builds a db and fills it with test-data. You can find it here https://gitlab.com/snippets/1957648

Comment: You're relying implicitly on `ForPath` here and that doesn't work with `ProjectTo`. But you entities/dtos are exactly reversed. `Car` should be in the DB, with a `Wheel` FK entity. And `CarDto` would show up in the UI, or whatever uses the DB.

Comment: Thanks for the input @LucianBargaoanu .  I opted for better db/class design in the future. Also if that's not "possible" my repo will now handle the dto as you suggested, which makes a lot of sense ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @LucianBargaoanu pointed out the `ProjectTo` doesn't work with `ForPath`. He also correctly pointed out that the logic/usage of my dto and entities is reversed.

In addition I wouldn't have to do the iqueryable-mapping if my db-design would match my `Car`and `Wheel` classes in a more class/object-related way or if my repo would expose and handle the dto class.

> You're relying implicitly on ForPath here and that doesn't work with ProjectTo. But you entities/dtos are exactly reversed. Car should be in the DB, with a Wheel FK entity. And CarDto would show up in the UI, or whatever uses the DB. – Lucian Bargaoanu